# Saving page views in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a users table in a mysql database as follows:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| recent      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I need to save the last 20 ids that a user has looked at. My first instinct was to use a string to hold a comma-delimited list, but that violates normalization. All I need to save are the 20 ids, and that it was a particular user who looked at them.

The best I can come up with, keeping normalization, is something like this:

```
users
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

users_pages
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| users_id    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| pages_id    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

pages
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| page01      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page02      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page03      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page04      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page05      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page06      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page07      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page08      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page09      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page10      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page11      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page12      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page13      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page14      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page15      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page16      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page17      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page18      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page19      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page20      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

But I know that's hardly ideal having numbers in column names. Also, I don't know how I would update the table on the 21st page view. It would need to update by placing the 21st page view in the page20 column, while page20 becomes page19, page19 becomes page18, etc. until page2 becomes page1, and the old page1 is forgotten.

I've head that something called CASCADE might be useful, but despite Googling I can't get a clear understanding of what it means or how to use it.

If it makes any difference, I'm accessing MySQL through PHP.

If anyone could give me a better idea of how to handle this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: No, that's not normalization either. Just store the id, and the page. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select page_id 
    from users_pages 
    where user_id = @user_id 
    order by id desc limit 20.
```

This should work, because the id of users_pages is auto_increment (and primary key), and unless you don't save the page views by the same order they were visited, a descendent sort will do the trick.

Comment: Some application frameworks don't play nice with `auto_increment` keys -- I recommend putting an insert timestamp to order by instead.

Comment: Paul, they have to work fine, because the id is also primary key...

by using the primary key to sort, there is no need to build and extra index and query performance will be delivered.

Comment: You can specify an ID to insert, and mysql will happily insert that.  Some frameworks (JPA comes to mind) will reserve blocks of IDs, so records that are inserted across a cluster may have out of order ids.  Of course, this depends on the configuration in question.  Just a "be careful out there" warning.

Comment: you are, indeed, correct Paul. I think is not the framework, but the key generator itself whom will give a certain amount of keys to each connection for "performance".

Comment: Thank you, what is the @user_id for? Does the pages table come into play here, or is this command doing something different?

Comment: Jessica the @user_id is a MySQL variable, it has the purpose to match the query for user id... you want the last 20 pages a certain user had visited? right?

the query returns only the 20 page_ids that meet the criteria requested by the original question...

Comment: Thanks, so that connects to the pages table somehow? Or is that not used here? I don't think I quite get it just yet.

Comment: Well, the query returns a set containing only page_id's. You can either do a sub-query or a join to extract more data from the pages table...

You need to have a page table that looks like this: create table pages (page_id int auto_increment, constraint  pk_pages primary key(page_id), page_url varchar(1024), ... );

Comment: Thank you, that got me thinking and I figured out a good way to handle things. I ended up using a different query though.